# How to print type definitions to Latex from Isabelle?

Tags: latex, isabelle

I'm using Isabelle document preparation for generating tex files. I wonder if there is an antiquotation for datatype definition so that it would be fully printed in latex.

In some file there is a definition

```
datatype t = A nat | B bool
```

And later I want to print this definition to latex. I didn't find any way how to do it in the Isabelle docs.

An antiquotation `@{datatype xyz}` was [mentioned](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/mailman/htdig/cl-isabelle-users/2012-December/msg00081.html) in the Isabelle mailing list, but it doesn't work for me (Isabelle 2013-2).

Does anybody know about an appropriate antiquotation for type definitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to work for me in Isabelle 2013-2.

The Isabelle theory file:

```
theory Baz
imports Main
begin

datatype t = A nat | B bool

text {*
  @{datatype t}
*}

end
```

results in the document:

[image: Output Isabelle Document]

The first `datatype` is the definition, while the second is the display anti-quotation.

Perhaps the problem is that your `@{datatype}` anti-quotation isn't in a `text {* ... *}` block?

Comment: Thanks, that worked. My problem was that I used a parametrized type, and the antiquotation shouldn't include the type parameter.